# How to customize the edit link in Views

Tags: 7, views

I have added an edit link before the title in my View by adding the field `Content: Edit link` on top in the fields list, excluding it from display and not adding any text in the field `"Text to display"`. I also rewrote the output of my title field like so: `[edit_node] [title]`.

That gives me a link with the text "Edit" just before the title (in spite of leaving the text field empty as explained above). But I would like to change that text into a symbol. I have tried a number of things including CSS, but I am stuck on this thing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does that 'Edit' has specific class or id? For symbol which module are you using?

Comment: Yes, I added a custom class for the Edit link under Style settings. For the symbol I am just using an image with size 16x16px.

Comment: So you are not using any module for image, that image is in your file, right? Are you not using FonAwesome module, in case?

Comment: No, I am not using any such modules.

Comment: Can you just post a screenshot of code of `Edit` which level upto <a>. This you can find using just doing `Inspect element` in browser. I wan to try in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply rewrite the results of `Content: Edit link` and add image with HTML.

```
<img scr=".....">
```

For Example:

[image]

Comment: Looks easiest and cleanest way for doing this, good to know.

Comment: Just one question, it is necessary to check `Exclude from display` option? Will it not hide rewrited part too, I mean entire field?

Comment: @CodeNext it is not necessary, I have removed it/updated pic to avoid confusion.

Comment: I tried that several times, but the image did not show. It turns out that I had another CSS rule that caused this. With some CSS adjustments I should be able to fix this now. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No, it does not hide the rewritten part, when used as a replacement pattern in another field (that must follow **after** the excluded field).

Comment: @NoSssweat I have one doubt, The Edit is a link, if we re-write this field, the link will also disappearance, what we will get is just image. I think somehow we need to add 'href' also for that.

Comment: @CodeNext I tested this, hence the screenshot. It works fine without the href part, as it looks to already have it "behind the scenes". So the re-write does not re-write the link part, unless you checkmark `Output this field as a link`

Comment: @TBJ If this solved your problem/question then don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark ✅ as per [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)